# could I say "you can pull it open to separate them" in this specific situation?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

> [pull](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pull) 1 /pʊl/ ●●● S1 W1 verb     1 MOVE SOMETHING TOWARDS YOU
>   [intransitive, transitive] to use your hands to make something or
>   someone move towards you or in the direction that your hands are
>   moving OPP push
>
> Mom! Davey’s pulling my hair!
>
> pull somebody/something into/away from/over etc something
>
> He pulled her down into her seat.
>
> pull something open/shut
>
> She pulled open the door and hurried inside.

---

Say, there are 2 bottles, you put the bigger one on the smaller one in a way that the inner neck of the bigger bottle **fitly contact** the outer neck of the smaller one as in this picture (the white one is a bit bigger than the green one).

[image]

To take the white one off the green one, you have to hold the green one with a hand and use the other hand to pull the white one up.

[image]

could I say "**you can pull it open to separate them**" in this specific situation?

Comment: I would use "detach"

Comment: You could say "pull them apart".

Comment: it really depends though, if you're writing instructions something like, "to detach, pull the cap" would do better.

Comment: Two bottles pushed together are still two bottles, not some new object, so you would say _them_ rather than _it_. I agree with Jack - _pull them apart_.